# Allocate free space to main ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 setup. I have made some changes in the partitions and now have a significant amount of un-allocated space, which I'd like to merge with, the main Ubuntu partition.

This is what my partitions look like:

[image: All the partitions including windows NTFS]

I'd love if someone could advise a way which could minimise the possibility of Data loss, as much as possible. That is keeping aside the physical factors ex: power loss, etc in consideration. In what way should the partitioning be done, so as to decrease the possibility of data loss.

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If what you want to achieve is merge the selected unallocated space with `/dev/sd4` you can simply right click on it, select *Resize/Move* and drag `/dev/sda4` to the right, taking as much unallocated space as you wish.

Comment: I was afraid, if i'd loose data that way. What i had thought of was, to simply resize the main partition and allocate the left over space. Should i go ahead with it?

Comment: As long as you do it following those instructions, there should not be any kind of data loss, as long as no abnormal error occurs, as you mentioned on your question.

Comment: I'll try it and post back.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with gparted run from a live Linux on a USB drive.

If you must minimize your machine downtime, and if you consider that moving/merging your partition with an automated tool like gparted is risky, here is what I would do for maximum safety + minimum downtime:

Step 1: create a `/dev/sda5` partition with the free 204 GB before your root partition.

Step 2: format at it (ext4), mount it and copy your root partition to it (e.g. `cp -ax`).

(consider that, from now on, any change to the original `/dev/sda6` partition will be lost, unless you resync later)

Step 3: add an entry to the grub menu in order to boot your system with the newly created partition.

Step 4: reboot on `/dev/sda5` and check that everything is ok

Step 5: remove `/dev/sda6` and add the remaining free space to `/dev/sda5` (i.e. grow it till the end of the disk). This can be done manually without any risk if you are careful (fdisk/gdisk + live resize2fs). This can probably be done (more?) safely with your graphical tool.

Done.

Comment: I simply resized my main partition, on a live disk. It completed without an error. Thanks for taking out the time.

Comment: @kartiksibal You're welcome. Glad it worked.